# hiding divs with negative margins on ipad

Tags: css, ipad, css-transforms, margins

I have an animation on `ipad` things go from `-200px` to `1500px` and are hidden in a browser with `overflow-x:hidden`.

When I look on `ipad` I can scroll `"off screen"` and see the hidden items even though the body and html and set to `width:100%` and `height:100%.`

How can I fix this in `ipad?`

Answer (score 0):

You might use media querys for the Ipad Viewport.

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the animation in a div that is not wider than the screen. Then apply `overflow:hidden;` on that div.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
html, body {
   position:relative;
}
```